# Insert data from modal without refreshing the page

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I want to create a modal that will not refresh my page but i don't know how. Some says i will use ajax but i'm confuse on how will i use ajax in my codes. please help me

VIEW:

```
  <div clas="container-fluid">
      <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Add Ingredients</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div clas="container-fluid">
      <?php echo form_open('dashboard/uploadIngredients', 'class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"'); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-10">

        <select required class="form-control" name="ingredient_category">

          <option value="" selected disabled>Select Ingredient Category</option>
      <option value="All">All</option>
      <?php foreach($this->products_model->getCategory() as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->category_id ?>"><?php echo $row->category_name; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="ingredients" rows="5" placeholder="Ingredients (EX. onion, oil, pasta)" required></textarea> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-positive" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Save Ingredient</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?></div></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div> </div> </div></div> </div>
    </div>

   </div>
```

CONTROLLER:

public function uploadIngredients()
    {

```
    foreach(explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredients')) as $key => $value)
        {
            if (!$this->products_model->getIngredientByName($value)) {
                $saveData[] = array(
                    'ingredient_id' => null,
                    'name'  => trim($value)
                );  
            }
        }

    $ingredient_id = $this->products_model->saveIngredients($saveData); 
    foreach (explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredient_category')) as $key => $value)
    {
     foreach ( $ingredient_id as $key => $str ){
        $joinData[] = array(
                            'ingredient_id'     => $str,
                            'category_id'       => intval($value)
        );
}
        //var_dump($joinData); die();
        $this->products_model->saveCategoryIngredients($joinData);

        redirect('dashboard/add_product');
        }


}/* end of uploadIngredients() */
```

MODEL:

```
public function saveIngredients($ingredient_id)
    {
        foreach($ingredient_id as $row => $value) {
            $query=$this->db->where('ingredient_id', $value->ingredient_id);
                $this->db->insert('ingredient', $value);
                $insert_id[] = $this->db->insert_id();  
        }
        return $insert_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

at the last form group you are using a button of type submit. whenever you hit the button it will submit all the data and refresh the page. so if you don't want to reload the page you should not use a submit type button. rather you can use a normal button with ajax function call.

example:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-positive" type="button" onclick="return ajaxFunction();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Save Recipe</button>
```

ajax example:

```
ajaxFunction(){
    $.ajax({
        url: //a php file's location that will receive and process all the data
        type: 'POST',
        data: //json or javascript object, for example, var1:'value1', in the php file you will get the value of var1 by using $_POST['var1'], if you use multiple variable as data then use a curly bracket with them, for example, {var1:'value1',var2:'value2'}
        success: function(response){
            //the response variable will hold anything that is written in that php file(in html) and anything you echo in that file
        }
     });return false;
}
```

Comment: You can put it below your html as internal javascript or you can use an external javascript file that will hold this ajax function. In short term, consider this ajax function as a javascript code and use it as you like.

Comment: im sorry but im confused. i dont know what i will put in url, data and in the success

Answer (score 1):

using ajax

it's a better way

```
$.ajax({
    url: "localhost/codeigniter-project/index.php/controller",
    type: "POST", // you can use GET
    data: {name: 'John'}, // post data
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); // after success
    }
});
```

Comment: i will not change anything in my codes other than putting this code for ajax?

Comment: you can change everything in this code (url, type, data, success)

Comment: In data you put a static data which is John. what if i want it to be dynamic?

Comment: you can use php tag (<?= $var; ?> or <?php echo $var; ?>)

or JavaScript Variables